# How to get average of the specific value from list in Kotlin? (same as maxOf)

Tags: kotlin

I have list of Location. Something like this:

`[{"latitude": "45.42123", "longitude": "44.32132", "speed": 4.3}, {"latitude": "46.212", "longitude": "45.4334", "speed": 5.2}]`

We have extensions in Kotlin so i can easily get max value of speed like this:

`myList.maxOf { it.speed }`

But how can i get average value of speed?

P.S. i found the same question in Java. I need solution in Kotlin.

Comment: Which average?  (Mean, median, mode…?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```kotlin
val average = myList.map { it.speed }.average()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
val average = myList.sumOf { it.speed } / myList.size
```

Comment: I can't use `sumOf` with Float :( can we just convert it to Double?

Comment: @SoulReaver313 ah I wasn't aware it was a Float. Arpit's answer should work then